# How to create friend request through API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

This is my status table

[image]

This is my friend request table

[image]

This is User table

[image]

This is my table creation, actually i want to create api of friend request, i am little bit confused in that...How can i create Friend Request API? when anyone request that how can i change status accept, reject?

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided is not sufficient enough to help you, rather than do the work for you.
First of all, based on table names, the way you have created this database structure is considered bad practice in Laravel. Please read this [Laravel documentation Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent). It should clear up things on Laravel models and migrations and after that, you should be able to answer the question yourself (at least get a grasp of the general idea of what you need).

Comment: How one user request another user through id? -@Kipras T

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand the question. -@Kinnu123

Comment: How one user send another user friend request ? _@KiprasT